# When and where to dismiss UIAlertController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am calling a method that executes a `URLSession` but before it does anything, presents a `UIAlertController` blocking the UI until some sort of response from the request is achieved. Logic tells me that dismissing the `UIAlertController` in the completion block of that method where it is called on the main thread would be the best option. Am I wrong to assume this? Apparently so, as variably the presented `UIAlertController` will indeed display, but never dismiss. Help?

Block:

```
getCostandIV { output in

            let cost = output["ask"] as! NSNumber
            let IV = output["IV"] as! NSNumber

            self.enteredCost = cost.stringValue
            self.enteredIV = IV.stringValue

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.progress.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: UITableView.RowAnimation.none)
                self.canWeSave()

            }

        }
```

Function:

```
 func getCostandIV (completionBlock: @escaping (NSMutableDictionary) -> Void) -> Void {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {


        self.progress = UIAlertController(title: "Retrieving ask price and volatility...", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        self.present(self.progress, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/chains?apikey=test&symbol=\(symbol)&contractType=\(type)&strike=\(selectedStrike)&fromDate=\(selectedExpiry)&toDate=\(selectedExpiry)") else {
        return
    }

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
            error == nil else {
                //print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {


                        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "There was an error retrieving ask price and volatility.", message: "Please try again later.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)

                    })

                }

                return }
        do{
            //here dataResponse received from a network request
            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                dataResponse, options: [])
            //                //print(jsonResponse) //Response result

            guard let jsonDict = jsonResponse as? NSDictionary else {
                return
            }
            //                //print(jsonDict)

            var strikeMap : NSDictionary = [:]

            if self.type == "CALL" {
                strikeMap = jsonDict["callExpDateMap"] as! NSDictionary

            } else {
                strikeMap = jsonDict["putExpDateMap"] as! NSDictionary

            }

            self.strikes.removeAllObjects()

            let inner = strikeMap.object(forKey: strikeMap.allKeys.first ?? "<#default value#>") as! NSDictionary
            let innerAgain = inner.object(forKey: inner.allKeys.first ?? "<#default value#>") as! NSArray
            let dict : NSDictionary = innerAgain[0] as! NSDictionary

            let dict2 = ["ask" : dict["ask"] as! NSNumber, "IV" : dict["volatility"] as! NSNumber] as NSMutableDictionary



            completionBlock(dict2)


        } catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Edit:** Using `self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` did not fix the issue. In addition, the completion block of the dismiss function for self.progress is not being called.

**Edit 2:** presentedViewController right before dismiss code in the callback is nil, even though present is called on the alert controller before dismiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this , for dismiss your alert you should add dismiss method in an async block and for setting timer for that you should tell async block to start being async from now to 5 seconds and after that do some thing :

```
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default,
                                      handler: nil))
        viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // change to desired number of seconds (in this case 5 seconds)
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
            // your code with delay
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: cause it dismiss automatically after the time you want , you can delete this part if you don't need .

Answer (score 0):

If you call the `getCostandIV` method more than once, the second alert won't be presented and `self.progress` will have the reference of unpresented alert.

Change

```
self.progress.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To

```
self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Just tried this and thought it was working for a second, but the first time getCostandIV is called, it never dismisses. Is there a better way I should handle presenting the alerts, maybe?

Comment: @ahjnar Use break point in this line and check whether the completion is called

Comment: Some potentially helpful info that I'm testing right now: delaying the dismissal of the alert with a timer is showing signs of working as of right now..

Comment: @ahjnar Show complete code of `getCostandIV` method.

Comment: Just did that and if I skip through the breakpoints (completion is called) the alert dismisses properly. Just not on its own..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195658/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-ahjnar).

Answer (score 0):

Your alert would be dismissed only if everything goes well.
I suggest you to change your function to something like this:

```
 func getCostandIV (completionBlock: @escaping (NSMutableDictionary?, Error?) -> Void) -> Void
```

and make sure that your `completionBlock` is called when your `guard` statements fail or an error is thrown. In your current code the alert is only dismissed when it network request fails, but not when something goes wrong when parsing JSON.

Comment: Not the answer to this problem, but upvoted for helpfulness! I will look into adding this. Thanks.